# Convert hex string value to hex int

Tags: java

How can I convert the `hexstring` into the form of `hexint` below?

```
string hexstring = "0x67";
int hexint = 0x67;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the overloads of `Integer.parseInt`? Note that by the time it's an `int`, the value doesn't have any particular format - so `int hexint = 0x67;` is precisely equivalent to `int hexint = 103;`

Comment: that makes sense now, I keep getting 103 when printing, thanks for the explanation

Comment: It's not quite addressing what you are asking for, but Java 17 introduced a new class **java.util.HexFormat** which frequently simplifies the solution to questions like this. In your case the only constraint is that your `hexstring` must only contain hex characters (i.e. _"67"_ rather than _"0x67"_), but then the solution is trivial:  `int hexint = HexFormat.fromHexDigits("67");`. That feels like a much more intuitive approach than `decode()` or `parseInt()` to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Integer#decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode-java.lang.String-) can be used to convert hexadecmial string representation into its integer value:

```
Integer.decode("0x67");
```

This function automatically detects the correct base and will parse return the int `103` (0x67 = 6*16+7). If you want to manually specify a different base, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74178260/112968)

Comment: Found you have posted two answers,why not merge them into one

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single byte, you can strip of the leading `"0x"` part and then parse as a base-16 number with `Integer#parseInt`:

```
Integer.parseInt("0x67".substring(2), 0x10);
Integer.parseInt("0x67".substring(2), 16);
```

0x10 is the hexadecimal representation of the decimal number 16.

Comment: You can use `Integer.decode` too.

Comment: @zhh thanks, made that into another answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hexstring = "67";
int hexint = Integer.parseInt(hexstring, 16);
System.out.println(hexint); // 103 (decimal)
```

With `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` you can parse a `String` to an `int`.

The `radix` is the base of that number system, in case of hex-values it is 16.